# AngularJS ng-repeat and indexOf() to check objects

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two json objects (data1 and data2) that have related information. Namely, both objects have properties (arrays) which in turn can have identical data. So, I am trying to figure out how to display those data with highlighting them properly, i.e. identical data with green color and non-identical with red color. Somehow it wrongly highlights all data with red color.

Here is the html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in vm.data2.features"
      ng-class="vm.data1.features.indexOf(item) !== -1 ? 'check' : 'uncheck'">
    <span ng-bind="item.id"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and objects:

```
vm.data1 = {
  id: '4569',
  name: 'Given data',
  features: [
    {id: "TEST_TEXT2", desc: 'smth12'},
    {id: "TEST_PPP", desc: 'smthsmthsmth'},
    {id: "TEST_ECASH", desc: "somelongtexthere"}
  ]
};

vm.data2 = {
  id: '1305',
  name: 'Base data',
  features: [
    {id: "TEST_BP", desc: 'smth'},
    {id: "TEST_TEXT2", desc: 'smth12'},
    {id: "TEST_PPP", desc: 'smthsmthsmth'},
    {id: "TEST_TEXT1", desc: 'blahblah'},
    {id: "TEST_ECASH", desc: "somelongtexthere"}
  ]
};
```

The full demo is [here](https://codepen.io/orif-jr/pen/JxJqyV?editors=1010).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Indexof()` method will look for similarity in object references not the id itself. `findIndex()` method can help you here instead.

```
vm.hasFeature = function(item){
var hasElements= vm.data1.features.findIndex(function(e){
  return e.id == item.id;
});
 console.log(item, hasElements);
 return hasElements;
}
```

And in html

```
<li ng-repeat="item in vm.data2.features"
    ng-class="vm.hasFeature(item) > -1 ? 'check' : 'uncheck'">
```

```
vm.hasFeature = function(item){
   var hasElements= vm.data1.features.findIndex(function(e){
      return e.id == item.id;
    });
    console.log(item, hasElements);
    return hasElements;
}
```

CodePen Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewgLBN?editors=1010

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Indeed, the method indexOf() is for references only. I got it after some investigation in docs.

Answer (score 1):

None of the objects will be the same because `indexOf(item)` will compare object references of `item`. You'll need to do a deep equals comparison of the items.

i.e.

```
{id: "TEST_TEXT2", desc: 'smth12'} === {id: "TEST_TEXT2", desc: 'smth12'} // false
vm.data1.features[0] === vm.data1.features[1] // false
```

Example using lodash would be something like:

`_.some(vm.data1.features, otherItem => _.isEqual(item, otherItem))`

Because

```
_.isEqual(vm.data1.features[0], vm.data2.features[1]) // true
```

Docs for Lodash:

- [_.some](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#some)
- [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual)

Comment: @MichaelYaworksi, thanks for the answer. solving the problem with lodash is actually much easier and I didn't thought about that :)